# What parts of math do I need in order to understand 3d programming? ( OpenGL )

Tags: android, math, opengl-es

I feel like Open GL ( on Android, and generally I assume ) is not so friendly to me. It may be the API but also I miss some math skills.

For example Vectors 3D, I know some theory ( pretty low ) about them, but fail to understand clearly the practical situations in which I need to use them.

I am thrilled about 3D programming, but having some pretty low math skills ( highschool ) and some concepts from faculty, I don't even know what kind of math I need for it.

Clueless, If someone would be to ask me what kind of math would it suffice for 3D, I would say matrix, vectors, geometry and trigonometry.

But I don't where do these belong ( Basic Algebra, Calculus, etc ).

So, can someone, tell me what are all the concepts needed to understand 3D programming and also enumerate some books ( beginner ones ) on each topic?

Comment: Matrix / Linear Algebra (matrix transformations) is a good place to start.

Comment: Calculus deals with the rates of how things change. For just "graphics", with no motion involved, start with Geometry. Linear algebra includes equations and techniques for transforming geometric objects (rotation, scaling, translation), and while does indeed involve "movement", it's not in the sense of speed (ie, calculus). For calc, your going to need to have your algebra down pat ( polynomials, sines/cosines, ...). Take a Calc I course if you can!

Comment: To begin with, I would suggest getting Visual Studio 20XY Express and use DirectX to get yourself started, as this will help reduce  technological obstacles that could hamper progress (you can easily get the OpenGL visual studio/c++/win32 libraries as well). Android is a beast to develop for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to learn depends on what you need to do.

For vector and matrix operations and coordinate systems you need **Linear algebra**. This is probably the most essential field of maths.

[The rendering equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_equation) and [Phong shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading) you need **Trigonometry and integrals**.

To understand rasterization you need **interpolation**.

If you want to define 3d shapes or textures mathematically some useful feilds of maths are **trigonometry, bezier curves, splines, fractal math** (depending on what kind of shape you want to define.

For some rendering effects such as [bump mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_mapping) you need **Partial derivatives**.

Also **numerical analysis** is useful in many cases to understand about precision in your calculations and also how to implement some kinds of operations effectively.

I'm sure that there's a lot more that can be relevant depending on what you want to do, but these are some things that come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a grasp of Linear Algebra; and for the book, this one is pretty good
[http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Programming-Computer-Graphics-Edition/dp/1435458869/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435458869)